# Sustainable way to get rid of rats?

Tags: food, pest-management, animals

Here where I live, there is a food store located beside my home.
Due to that, there is a problem with rats and because of the rats, lots of other problems occur. They cut up many things and defile the food. So I want to get rid of this problem. Please suggest some ideas how to get rid of these rats *without using toxic pesticides*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the food source that is attracting the rats is the food store next to you, you should talk with the owners of the store about taking one or more of the following measures:

1. Make sure the rats cannot access any food or leftovers. This may be hard to do as rats can eat their way through various materials. Storing all food and garbage in metal containers will help. Also keep your place as clean as possible, so don't leave and food leftovers on the table and sweep or vacuum the floor regularly.
2. Locate and seal all holes and entry points to your house to keep the rats out. You'll have to use very sturdy materials for this (metal or very thick wood). Rats are very good climbers so also check for holes at window frames and ceilings. Also check if there are no tree branches or bushes the rats can use to climb on your roof and access the house from there.
3. Get a cat. The cat will catch some of the rats and hopefully drive away the remaining rats.
4. Buy and place [rat traps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_trap). There are traps that kill a rat (snap traps), but also traps that just contain the rat (live traps) so you can release them several miles away from your home.
5. Use an eco-friendly rat repellent. I've never tried those myself, but I've heard they may help (a little). Rats can't stand the smell of peppermint, so place peppermint plants around your house or soak some rags with peppermint oil. Rats also don't like moth balls and the smell of predators so dropping cat litter around your house if you have access to it may also help.

If you take the same measures as your neighbour the rats will hopefully have to go elsewhere.

Don't use any poison because it's dangerous for children  and the smell of a decomposing rat somewhere in your wall or ceiling isn't pleasant. Also a poisoned rat may contaminate the enviroment if they die outside or poison cats and dogs if they find and eat the dead rat.

Comment: yeah i will follow this

Comment: As much as I love the idea of adopting a cat from a local shelter(because that is the responsible thing to do) a cat is actually going to prolong the problem because the cat will basically cull the weakest of the rats leaving more food available for the stronger which will just reproduce resulting in stronger generations in the future.  Unless you kill them all or all of the females at least this is not going to have the expected results

Comment: @Chad You may be right. I guess it will depend on the number of rats in the first place and on how long they already live in your house. I suspect that the longer the rats are present, the less likely they are too flee elsewhere when you get a cat.

Comment: [Caveats](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/01/30/science/that-cuddly-kitty-of-yours-is-a-killer.html?_r=0) for the `Get a cat.` option.

Answer (score 8):

## Outdoors

Snakes and owls are the rat's natural predators out doors. If you can encourage their population in or near your yard you will decrease the rat population. Any bird of prey will hunt rats but Owls especially because they are nocturnal so they are most active when the rat is. Rodents are not fond of the smell of mint or citronella. Planting these plants around your home may discourage them.

## Indoors

Your number one defense is to make life uncomfortable for them. Getting rid of their food source. This may not be easy since rat's can chew through wood, plastic and even metal. Refrigerated and frozen food is usually safe from rats since they'll avoid the cold if other food sources are more readily available.

Many rat breeds live outside and only infiltrate a home in search of food. If food is available outside they will have no reason to enter your home. Encouraging them to stay outdoors will expose them to greater attacks from predators. You could try bating them by leaving food scraps for them as far from your house as possible.

Repair any holes you find in the exterior of your house. Some breeds prefer to live in trees but a warm attic is a tempting offer so check there for holes as well. Cat's have already been mentioned for indoors but a ferret may be a better choice. Ferrets will attack and overpower prey much larger than themselves.

Rat's will stay hidden if given a choice. If you see rats out in the open then they were probably forced into the open by over population and you or your neighboring food store have an entrenched infestation.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get a sticky rat mat, then place it in areas where they are sure to come. You can get scented mats, for e.g peanut butter etc. From your name, it appears you are from India. I was able to get those from local stores in Bangalore. One for your reference http://www.gluetraps.co.uk/rat-glue-trap-boards-2-c.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you're next to a feed lot of some sort, it's next to impossible to get rid of the rats completely.  I live in a rat infested neighborhood and have done the following.

- Call the county and asked them to put out poison.  There are two bait stations placed and maintained by the county in the creek that goes through my yard.
- Pick them off one by one. Rat traps and an electric rat zapper.

With a massive rodent problem, it may require rallying the community and working with the owner of the feed lot to get it under control.
http://pauledmondson.hubpages.com/hub/kill-rats

Comment: How do your solutions relate to *sustainability*?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR** - Get a straight edged bucket, put one handful of chicken/rabbit/duck pellets and half fill with water. Put in easy to access area. The greedy buggers will jump and won't be able to climb out.

---

I accidentally discovered this because we had a rat population explosion in our yard due to heavy rain and an abundance of food a few months ago.

I am in the suburbs, but many of my neighbours and myself included have a large variety of animals (rabbits, chickens, ducks etc.), thus there is plenty of scraps around for scavengers.

I don't like using rat poison because I don't want them to drag it into the cage of my animals and we also have a large amount of native wildlife in the area.

I had a bucket next to our ducks which had a very little bit of feed in the bottom. One day when I was scratching my head about how to deal with the rats, I noticed there were 3 dead rats floating in the rainwater which had pooled in the bucket.

I emptied the bucket (fun job!) and tried this again by putting a hand-full of duck pellets in the bottom of the bucket and half filled it with water. Within two days I had another three dead rats. Rinse and repeat!

This works best if you put the buck near where the rats are entering your property and near where they are used to finding other food. You don't want them to have to go out of their way to discover your trap.

You also need to make the bucket accessible. They are not going to climb up the side of bucket to get in, if they can't climb up the side of the same bucket to get out. Place it underneath a tree or next to a fence or some rocks, anything they can climb on to get in.

Lastly, the bucket I used had straight sides, I'm not sure if they can easily climb out of a standard bucket (the type you get at supermarkets). My bucket was also slightly deeper than a traditional bucket.